# Laravel disable specific filter for specific route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using `Route::when('*', 'csrf', ['post','put'])` to enable csrf filter, now I have a route that doesn't need csrf filter, how to disable filter on this route?

```
Route::post('/process', 'MyController@process'); // I need to disable csrf filter for this route
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but did you try doing this:

```
Route::post('/process', array('before' => '', 'uses' => 'MyController@process'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do this in your routes file:

```
Route::post('/process', 'MyController@process');

Route::group(['before' => 'csrf'], function () {
      // All your other routes here
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have already grouped my routes by prefix, if this is the only solution then I need to separate group for each prefix to add `before => csrf` just because one route :-/

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. I meant in each group (with each `prefix`) there are `get`, `post` and `put` routes, so I need to separate them and there are many.

Answer (score 0):

It seems either I can specify regex for route path in `Route::when` or using `Route::whenRegex`, or create my own filter so I can check what route(s) to be excluded:

```
Route::filter('mycsrf', function($route, $request) {

    // check excluded routes 
    if ($route->getName() == 'route.name')
        return;

    // call original csrf filter
    Route::callRouteFilter('csrf', [], $route, $request);
});

Route::when('*', 'mycsrf', ['post', 'put']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to handle filters in the `\BaseController` than the route itself.

```
$this->afterFilter('@pushUpdateToSqsQueue', ['on'=>'post', 'except' =>
            ['postToggle']
        ]
);
```

The above will apply a custom `after` filter, to all routes that `POST` to any of the endpoints in my controller or controller classes that extend it.

Unless the method I'm posting to is `postToggle` in whcih case ther filter is not applied.